shifted convolution in arithmetic progressions
Let $r(n)$ be the number of ways of writing $n$ as the sum of two integer squares. Asymptotics for the shifted convolution problem $$ \sum_{n\in \mathbb N\cap[1,x]}r(n) r(n+1)$$ are quite classical; a proof can be found in Iwaniec--Kowalski's book Analytic Number Theory, Corollary 15.12.
My question is whether there is a paper proving asymptotics when $n$ lies in a fixed arithmetic progression? i.e. fix $q\in \mathbb N$ and $a\in \mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$. Can we prove asymptotics as $x\to \infty $ for the sum
$$ \sum_{\substack{ n\in \mathbb N\cap[1,x] \\
 n \equiv a \mod q}}r(n) r(n+1)?$$
I am not interested in the quality of the error term or even how it depends on $q$.

I have not seen this in the literature. As to whether we can prove asymptotics - sure, the techniques exist, but it'd be a fair amount of work.

Fixing $q=4$ and $a=2$ (or $a=3$), the asymptotic is zero, as is the error term.

I also haven't seen this in the literature. Some of my work is closely related, so I think I would have seen it if it were out there. But I also think this is obtainable. Do you have an application in mind?

yes-to rational points. i can prove it in 1 page using a result of tolev givinglevel of distribution 2/3 for r. But it is an annoying one page.
